# AndroidStudio doesn't recognize R

Tags: android-studio

I am teaching android app programming at a highschool. I found Eclipse to fragile so we are now trying out Android Studio. But a couple of students get that Android Studio with `R.` in red font, showing that it is not recognized.

This happened for example when the student copied the contents of my files.

Comment: Invalid characters in resource file names? Valid chars are `a...z`, `0...9`, `.` and `_`. No numbers at the beginning of file name, no spaces, no upper case, no strange characters, ...

Comment: (Re)build the project can also help

Comment: Make them import your project, not copy it. If they copy just some files, they're bound to miss some files that your source code depends on.

Comment: You found an android development tool to be fragile?  That's craaaaaazy

Comment: Good choice in doing the switch. Fragility's never been an issue with ADT for me but AS is the future of Android programming; it's beneficial for them for sure. Regardless of the reason a lab atmosphere might be the best to get everyone on the same page. As a group get the base app up. This problem could be for many other reasons than guessed at in comments and answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sometimes happens when you open a proyect from other sources. Just Synchronize it or press Ctrl-Alt-Y.

Answer (score 3):

`R.java` file issues : 1) check the naming convention of images in `drawable` folder with size. 
  2) check the `style` of your application

In your case it may be missing `style` .. So upadate the `style` in `value` folder as per application .

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason for this error is bad XML coding. For example using `android:src="@drawable@drawable/picture"` in `ImageView` will give you R error as it will not let R.Java file to build. Its hard to trace such errors as XML file will not show any error.

Also take a look if your resources are of good quality!

Hope it helps! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Build -> Clean Project
> 2. Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

and all OK!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

[image]

to `gradle.properties` and Refresh:

[image]

You can also do the following: Clean Project and Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Comment: this property is obsolete and has no effect

Answer (score 0):

try importing your project :

> To migrate existing Android projects, simply import them using Android Studio:
>
> 1. In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see the Welcome to Android Studio window.
> 2. Click Import Non-Android Studio project.
> 3. Locate the project you exported from Eclipse, expand it, select the build.gradle file and click OK.
>
> In the following dialog, leave Use gradle wrapper selected and click OK. (You do not need to specify the Gradle home.)
> Android Studio properly updates the project structure and creates the appropriate Gradle build file.

Comment: Occasionally the problem exists when an android-studio project is imported. What is the right way to do that type import?

Comment: just go to File > Import Project

Comment: in case of problem doing this imports try Rebuild or build from Build Menu, sometimes you just need to wait that Gradle do his work

Answer (score 0):

First if the existing project was developed in eclipse you need to import the project and then check what are the error. If your students are coping codes from your project then after coping the codes they need to clean and sync the project. If still your problem not solved try this in android studio :-

File/invalidate caches/restart.

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Especially, for regeneration of `R.Java` file.

If you have tried all these options:

> - Clean Project
> - Rebuild Project
> - Invalidate Caches / Restart
> - deleted .gradle folder
> - deleted .idea folder
> - deleted app/build/generated folder
> - checked your xml files
> - checked your drawables and strings

and still face problem then check your classpath dependency in your Project Gradle Scripts and if it's, this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

then downgrade it to, this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

clean and rebuild it will sync your project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the lint gave me a hand...

If you're using lint, it can help too.

In **gradle.build(Module:app)** add the **lintOptions** sub-element in **android** element as shown below, then lint will fix it for you!!.

```
android {

  lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
  }
}
```

I hope it helps!!